# Populate Textbox using Populated Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have one Dropdown list which I have populated from the database.. and i have 3 textboxes

now i wants to retrieve the data into textboxes from the database by selecting item in dropdown..

Please help me to retrieve the data into texboxes using javaScript..

Thanks in Advance..

my code is for dropdown:

```
<select name="select" class="form-control" id="selected" onchange="UpdateTextbox(this)">
<option id="0">-- Select the Company --</option>
   <?php
      require("dbcon.php");

      $getallcompanies = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ifcandetails6");

      while($viewallcompanies = mysql_fetch_array($getallcompanies)){
                                            ?>
 <option id="<?php echo $viewallcompanies['tcuid']; ?>"><?php echo $viewallcompanies['tcname'] ?></option>
       <?php
         }
       ?>
```

Code for textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="myvalue" placeholder="Trade Centre Contact No." value="<?php echo $viewallcompanies['tccontact']?>" disabled/>
```

Mysql Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ifcandetails6` (
`tcuid` int(100) NOT NULL,
`tcname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`tccontact` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`tccperson` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`tcemail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`tcdesig` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`tcaddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will select all the texts in your drop down and put it in your text box.

If its not exactly what you want you can either modify it or say so.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<select id="me">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<script>
$(function () {
   var $string = "";
   $("#me option").each(function () {
     $string += $(this).text();
   });
   $("#textbox").val($string);
});
</script>
```

Cheers.